# Android Payment Methodology

Tags: android, payment-gateway

I wanted to know what are option available to do online payment. Some of option I know Paypal, In-App Purchase. How can achieve following methodology like via ***Visa Card*** or ***Net Banking***.

Any suggestion here!

Answer (score 0):

Same way java and php go to this link : check out :

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/mobile/mobile-sdk-overview/

[GitHub Paypal](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK)

Comment: This is same I mention in question. What are other payment gateway option available. Apart how to get Net Banking and Visa payment feature in app. Any idea about these.

Comment: Raaz, Thanks for sharing. As I mention I wanted to know other methodology apart Paypal.